# Using ElementRef vs JQuery in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I have tried consistently to avoid JQuery in my angular2 app mainly due to the advice of more experienced folks regarding **direct DOM access**. Now I'm working on a draggable directive which uses ElementRef. Considering ElementRef also accesses DOM elements directly, I was wondering if there is any advantage between using JQuery or this Directive.

Answer (score 3):

It seems direct DOM access isn't frowned upon anymore, using jQuery still is. The Angular team is updating the docs to use `elementRef.nativeElement` directly instead of `Renderer`
Only if you want to use web workers or server side rendering you have to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery, you have a library that is specifically designed for DOM manipulation. Some operations will certainly be easier or shorter. But direct DOM access with *ElementRef* should also be avoided. *ViewChild + local template* variable is often the nicer choice. Take a look here: https://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html